# Web application with automatic "service" - which options?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a web app (MVC) where I need some "automatic service" to run some background operations. This service (can be inside of my web app's source code) needs to run every X minutes/hours/days.

I need to be sure that this code will run even if the website does not receive any web request and even if the main server restart.

At this point I only see "windows service" as an option. But for my case I am not allowed to do it in this server (server #1) and I do not like the idea to have this service on some other machine (server #2) to perform "web requests" to the server #1.

`WinScheduler` isn't an option as well.

Do you guys have some other solution?

Thank you.

**UPDATE #1**

Is there anyway for the IIS 7 to "wake up" my application without any "web request"?

**UPDATE #2**

I can not use "url requests" to wake up the application (and my automatic services)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at : http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/ . This is an awesome library for automated jobs. Hope it helps